# Jupyter, cant delete cell with shortcut esc d d

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts

It worked, as expected, always, until it didn't. I have no idea what happened. Just all of a sudden, `esc d d` stopped working. I can, however, toggle a cell from code to markdown with shortcuts. I can also delete a cell via right click context menu. I've tried restarting my browser and clearing the cache. I've tried both notebook and lab.

Windows 10
Chrome browser

```
(tf2gpu) PS C:\Users\lab> jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.27.0
ipykernel        : 6.4.1
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.0.3
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : 1.11.0
jupyterlab       : 3.1.13
nbclient         : 0.5.4
nbconvert        : 6.1.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.4
qtconsole        : 5.1.1
traitlets        : 5.1.0
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarted the computer, now it works. Gotta love technology....